# Is it valid to add a file descriptor to epoll with events set to zero?

Tags: c++, c, linux, epoll

Is it valid to add a file descriptor to epoll with epoll_event.events set to zero? What can be expected to happen when calling epoll_wait? See abridged example:

```
struct epoll_event event = {};
event.data.fd = fd;
event.events = 0;

epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &event);
epoll_wait(efd, &event, 1, -1);
```

What semantics can I rely on from the epoll_wait call in this instance? Are there any events that are still delivered even when events = 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be valid, and the `EPOLLERR` and `EPOLLHUP` are always included even if you're not requesting them, so setting `events = 0` will still respond on those 2 events.
Remember to check the return value of `epoll_ctl` though.

The documentation states:

> The events member is a bit mask composed by ORing together **zero or more** of the following  available event types:
>
> EPOLLERR
>                 Error  condition happened on the associated file descriptor.  This event is also reported for the write end of a pipe
>   when the read end has been closed.  **epoll_wait(2) will always report
>   for this event; it is not nec‐
>                 essary to set it in events.**
>
> EPOLLHUP
>                 Hang up happened on the associated file descriptor.  **epoll_wait(2) will always wait for this event; it is not necessary to set it in events.**

Comment: Okay, I did read the docs but missed the part about EPOLLERR and EPOLLHUP. Thanks.